# R XBRL with local cached xsd's

Tags: r, xbrl

I am trying out **R** and the [XBRL library](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XBRL/XBRL.pdf), and am having some difficulties with **caching**.

My xbrl-files have links to xsd's that can't be reached. The url's just produce 404's.

I have downloaded the taxonomies and have placed them in a folder structure like this:

URL: `http://archprod.service.eogs.dk/taxonomy/20141220/cmn_rol.xsd`

Path: `http` / `archprod.service.eogs.dk` / `taxonomy` / `20141220` / `cmn_rol.xsd`

I have download all xbrl's and all xsd's. Now I just want the R XBRL library to use the cached files instead of trying to download them.

Any idéas? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem.
I've been talking to a colleague who worked at eogs.dk earlier.
It seems like they have moved the endpoint for the taxonomy. On their website they post the following - maybe it has something to do with eogs.dk moving to a new system/procedure?

*"Erhvervstyrelsen forventer, at det bliver muligt at indberette digitale årsrapporter efter årsregnskabslovstaksonomi 20161001 senest primo januar 2017
Nedenfor finder du den nye taksonomi samt vejledning og information hertil."*

Translated from danish it says that they are expecting that electronic financial reporting will be made possible from 2016 - primo 2017.

Hope they soon will post an update on this issue, and update the current documentation.

Comment: Thanks :) I'll keep an eye on their website.

Comment: UPDATE: After working more with this issue I have found that the endpoint is not missing, in fact it is intended to do so. You have to host the xsd's your self, and point at the entrypoint file from the XBRL document. 
However I am still having a hard time getting all data out of the Danish XBRL documents.

Comment: Yeps, I have also downloaded the taxonomies... so that is not an issue. I was trying to get R to use the cache instead of trying to fetch from the dead link endpoints.

Comment: I was in contact with the creator of Gepsio framework for parsing XBRL Taxonomies. It seems like the danish government is not complying to the standards of the xbrl, and is only providing access to some of the information contained in the danish xbrl documents :/
Did you manage to get any further regarding this issue?

Comment: I am the author of the Gepsio framework that @GustavKastrupNielsen referenced in his message above. He is correct. I had to add code to Gepsio to look for schemas locally if the schema reference link was dead. I hope that your XBRL package can do the same.

Comment: @GustavKastrupNielsen Yes I solved it by using [Arelle](https://github.com/Arelle/Arelle), where I can use locally stored schemas. I have not tried Gepsio.

Comment: @swenedo great I managed to get some of the way with Arelle as well :)